# Ao selecionar opção preço vai para "0"

Tags: magento

Estou utilizando a versão 1.8.1.0 do [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) para desenvolver uma loja de cosméticos, e estou enfrentando problemas com preço de produtos configuráveis.

Estou utilizando o [SCP](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html). O produto vem com o preço padrão, e ao selecionar a opção (no caso é medida em ML) ML o preço vai para "0".

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Diogo, seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Fiz uma pequena edição no seu post, então confira aí se ainda reflete sua intenção original. Caso queira, você pode também editar o post, ou mesmo reverter a edição. Inclusive, seria bom mesmo você editar a pergunta, para incluir o trecho de código que está dando problema, pois isso aumenta bastante as chances de receber a resposta que procura.